# How to make Doctrine 2.1 quote identifiers with ZF1 using Bisna?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am using the ZF + Doctrine 2.1 implementation by Ralph Schindler (https://github.com/ralphschindler/NOLASnowball/tree/doctrine2-managed-crud).

My MySQL database uses some reserved words, a column named order. I need to tell Doctrine to quote identifiers, but I can't seem to get it to work in the application itself nor in the scripts/doctrine.php (https://github.com/ralphschindler/NOLASnowball/blob/doctrine2-managed-crud/scripts/doctrine.php) to use the command line tool.

Note: I'm reverse engineering my database by using the command:

`php scripts/doctrine.php orm:convert-mapping --from-database annotation library/app/Entity/`

which gives the error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1

because the column order doesn't get quoted with ticks.

Comment: Apologies if you've already checked the Doctrine manual, but if not, section 5.9 says all you have to do is add the character ` to both sides of the column name in your annotation. So yours would be @Column(name="`order`", type="integer")

Comment: Thank you cantera25, I have read that but I'm trying to reverse engineer the database. So Doctrine will create the Entities for me by running the above script. Therefor Doctrine self needs to add the ticks when checking.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was misreading column 'order' as 'column order'. Will research further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found it.

It appears the NOLASnowBall demo app uses an older Doctrine than the current stable. With Doctrine 2.1.4 the ticks are added, without the need to set the extra option.

I have updated Doctrine and took the new Bisna library from Guilherme Blanco's repository at https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2